# What is the best way to make an evaluation with row values and insert the result as a new column in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a pandas dataframe like that;

```
DATE        TICKER     PRICE
2016-1-2     AA           10   
2016-1-3     AA           11
2016-1-4     AA           12
```

I want to evaluate price change by dividing current row value to previous row value. And then insert it as a new column. I will do that for all rows in dataframe.

I tried to do it in a for loop, iterate all rows one by one and did calculation. Is it the best way to do it or is there a more efficient method to do this?

Comment: `df['new'] = df['PRICE'] / df['PRICE'].shift()` ?

Comment: When I try that, it raises an error. SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

Comment: That warning has nothing to do with _this_ code. The warning is letting you know you’re _setting_ to a copy of a slice which means at some point _before_ this code you’ve unsafely subset the dataframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to what @HenryEcker said, you can use pandas `pct_change()` function.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'DATE': ['2016-1-2', '2016-1-3', '2016-1-4'],
    'TICKER': ['AA', 'AA', 'AA'],
    'PRICE': [10, 11, 12]
})

df['RETURN'] = df['PRICE'].pct_change()
```

This returns the following data frame

```
    DATE    TICKER  PRICE   RETURN
0   2016-1-2    AA  10      NaN
1   2016-1-3    AA  11      0.100000
2   2016-1-4    AA  12      0.090909
```

Comment: When I try that, it raises an error. SettingWithCopyWarning: A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame. Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

Comment: I'll echo what @Henry Ecker said. Have you started out with a much larger data set and created a subset from it at some point?

Comment: Yep,  that is what I am doing. df_raw is larger dataset. First, I am generating a new dataset by filtering df_raw. That is the code. df_ticker = df_raw[df_raw["TICKER"]==ticker]
    df_ticker["RETURN"] = df_ticker["CLOSE"].pct_change()*100

Comment: Try `df_ticker = df_raw.loc[df_raw['TICKER']==ticker]` and then apply any functions.  If the answer above with `pct_change()` helped you, you should accept it.